# How do I get a template to $compile with UI Bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create dynamic template for `uib-popover`.  The popover declaration is in a loop of `settlements`.  Here is the popover declaration:

```
<a
    ng-click="noop($event)"
    popover-title="{{settlement.name}} ({{settlement.age}}) {{settlement.gender}}"
    popover-trigger="'focus'"
    popover-placement="auto top"
    tabindex="0"
    uib-popover-template="getHtml(settlement)"
>{{settlement.name}}</a
```

Here is my `getHtml`:

```
let url = `/settlment/${settlement.id}`;
let button = $scope.isParent ? `<a class="btn btn-default" on-click="clickButton()">${partInfo}</a>` : "";
let html = `<div class="popver">
                <p>${settlement.person ? "Person" : ""}</p>
                <p>${mrnLabel}: ${mrn}</p>
                ${button}
            </div>`;
```

Being that I need the `on-click`, I need a template so the html will be bound to the `$scope`.

I have tried many different things in the js.  I tried to just return `$compile(html){$scope}`, but I get an error.

```
[$parse:isecdom] Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is disallowed!
```

I have tried adding directly to the `$templateCache`, but then the button doesn't show.  I have tried `$compile`ing and adding to the `$templateCache` and the button still doesn't show.  What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: shouldn't it be `$compile(html)($scope)` ?

Comment: That is what I used.  It is in the question above.  Maybe I should make it more visible in the question.